# how to handel httpParamSerializerJQLike using JAVA JSON Restfull WebService

Tags: java, android, angularjs, json, web-services

There are two plateform one is client `Android App` that POST JSON data using `httpParamSerializerJQLike` and other one is **JAVA JSON Restfull WebService** that store JSON data in MySQL database

The problem is that when client POST JSON data like `{"publisher":{"number":"25364"}}` then **httpParamSerializerJQLike** convert that to `=%7B%22publisher%22:%7B%22number%22:%25364%22%7D%7D`
if we remove **httpParamSerializerJQLike** from client code then JSON is not change and JAVA WebService get proper JSON like `{"publisher":{"number":"25364"}}`

I want to know how can i convert `=%7B%22publisher%22:%7B%22number%22:%25364%22%7D%7D` to JSON like `{"publisher":{"number":"25364"}}`

My Code is

```
package com.lb.jersey;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/xyz")
public class RegistrationService
{
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Path("/abc1")
    public String Insert (String json)
    {
        System.out.println("Json>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+json);
        retrun json;
    }
}
```

My web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Jersey REST Service</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.lb.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am using Eclipse Mars.1, Tomcat8 and MySQL.